# how to remove a row from datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I'm trying to remove/delete 1 row from `datatable` which has 100 rows like this:

```
Form1.dt.Rows[i].Delete();
Form1.dt.AcceptChanges();
```

but further down when i get the count of the rows of the table like :

```
int rc = Form1.dt.Rows.Count;
```

the rc still returns 100! does `Form1.dt.Rows[i].Delete();` clear the row and leave it empty there or delete the row completely from table? and how can i remove that row form the `dt`?

Comment: Did you try `Form1.dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);`

Comment: @Vlad i just did and it seems like its working. thank you. please write it as an answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick instead of `Delete` and `AcceptChanges`:

```
Form1.dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
```

**Update**: Caution when using a `DataAdapter` and relational data source along with your `DataTable`. Using `Remove` modifies the `DataTable`, but not the actual data source. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03c7a3zb(v=vs.110).aspx